# Python QuickSort only partially sorting

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I'm learning the quicksort algorithm, but for some reason, the output of this python implementation is just partially sorted, and I get the 'maximum recursion depth reached' for larger inputs. I've been banging my head against this for the last couple of days and I know it's probably something really stupid, but I can't seem to figure it out, so I'll appreciate any help.

```
def ChoosePivot(list):
    return list[0]  

def Partition(A,left,right):
    p = ChoosePivot(A)
    i = left + 1

    for j in range(left + 1,right + 1): #upto right + 1 because of range()
        if A[j] < p:
                A[j], A[i] = A[i], A[j] #swap
                i = i + 1
    A[left], A[i - 1] = A[i-1], A[left] #swap
    return i - 1

def QuickSort(list,left, right):
    if len(list) == 1: return   
    if left < right:
        pivot = Partition(list,left,right)              
        QuickSort(list,left, pivot - 1)
        QuickSort(list,pivot + 1, right)
        return list[:pivot] + [list[pivot]] + list[pivot+1:]

sample_array = [39,2,41,95,44,8,7,6,9,10,34,56,75,100] 
print "Unsorted list: " 
print sample_array
sample_array = QuickSort(sample_array,0,len(sample_array)-1)
print "Sorted list:"
print sample_array
```

Comment: You should be thinking of the algorithm at a much higher level. That's how you might write it in a language such as C. It would be better to think of it functionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirley sure this is the issue, but you are chosing pivot wrongly:

```
def ChoosePivot(list):
    return list[0]  
def Partition(A,left,right):
    p = ChoosePivot(A)
    ....
```

You are always taking the head of the original list, and not the head of the modified list.

Assume at some point you reduced the range to left=5,right=10 - you chose list[0] as the pivot - that can't be good.

As a result, in each iteration where `left>0` you ignore the first element in the list, and "miss" it - which can explain the partial sorting

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Cheers amit!

Answer (score 1):

```
def ChoosePivot(list):
    return list[0]
```

As amit said, this is wrong. You want `p = A[left]`. However, there is another issue:

```
if A[j] < p:
    A[j], A[i] = A[i], A[j] #swap
i = i + 1
```

The pivot index should only be incremented when you swap. Indent `i = i + 1` to the same depth as the swap, as part of the `if` statement.

Bonus question: Why are you partitioning twice?

Answer (score 0):

also last swap;

A[left], A[i - 1] = A[i-1], A[left] #swap

should be done with pivot.

Besides that Quicksort works inplace. So you don't need following return;

return list[:pivot] + [list[pivot]] + list[pivot+1:]

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I believe it's still of most relevance.

Choosing a pivot always on the same position when implementing quicksort is a flaw on the algorithm. One can generate a sequence of numbers that makes your algorithm run in O(n^2) time, and absolute run time probably worse than bubblesort.

In your algorithm, choosing the leftmost item makes the algorithm run in worst-case time when the array is already sorted or nearly sorted.

**The choice of the pivot should be performed randomly to avoid this issue.**

Check the algorithms' Implementation issues in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Implementation_issues

Actually, check the hole article. It IS worth your time.

Comment: Choosing a pivot randomly only reduces the likelihood of running in worst-case time since there is nothing to stop the computer from randomly choosing the worst pivot - so to say random selection will avoid the issue is incorrect.  Another way to select the pivot to try and avoid having quicksort run in quadratic time is to use the median-of-three approach - take the first, last and middle values, and select the median value.